# запуск exe от pyinstaller от имени администратора

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Такой вопрос: есть скрипт Python, упакованный в ехе pyinstaller'ом. как сделать так, чтобы ехе всегда открывалось от имени администратора? (галочка в свойствах не подойдет, --uac-admin тоже не дает результатов)

Comment: это зависит от операционной системы. На *nix, можно `setuid` у исполняемого файла выставить.

Comment: @jfs windows 7,server 2008-2012

Comment: уак админ ничего не даст, если упаковано в один файл.

Comment: @RomanKatzendorn, ничего непонятно.

Comment: Манифест приложения.